# Why do I keep having to replace my starter?

Tags: chevrolet, starter, truck

I have a 1996 Chevy c1500 w/t v6 Vortec & I replaced the starter & flywheel & it ran for a couple months then the starter stopped hitting the flywheel (it just sounded like it was spinning) & wouldn’t start again, shims didn’t work. Got a new starter & it starts again but every couple months I have to warranty the starter & put a new one in. I’m on my 4th starter. Why does it keep going through starters?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What is wrong with the starters? Are the teeth worn? Do the protract when voltage is applied or do they only spin? I would do CSI on your bad one for clues

Comment: Adding shims moves the teeth away from the flywheel in many cases - are you sure you are going the right way?

Comment: My opinion is to release engine belt and try to rotate the following
Alternator pulley , A/C compressor pulley , adjuster pulley, water pump pulley
If they are all fine , it might be a ( bended crankshaft) Question, if you accelerate do you her like ( ttrrrrr) sounds from engine?

Comment: One the starters the teeth were bent & I have shimmed it with all different size shims could try & they hit to hard once it’s shimmed. 
No the engine sounds normal very strong.

Comment: The teeth would bend in different directions if it is caused by the torque of the starter motor or the engine when it starts.  Which way are they being bent?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the failures can vary. Are the starters new, rebuilt or remanufactured? It is possible that the rebuilder  was supplied with  a substandard component. If that is the case, you will be replacing your starter until that inventory is used up. Talk to your supplier and see if they can source you a different brand or perhaps the next model up in the price tier.

Comment: I have two starters I put in one is the one the part store comes up with that’s made for my truck & the other is for high torque & they both last only a couple months before they stop hitting the flywheel.